# Cannot find one variable from .XML file, but others are found. Why is this?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So I am having issues compiling my code in `Android Studio`. In my `onCreate()` method, I have multiple references to my `contentView` called `activity_game.xml.` However, I am unable to find the variable `time` `(R.id.time)` and I am unsure why.  I have tried to clean project then rebuild, No luck. I have tried to set the text directly below thinking maybe the issue is how I am filling time, this also did not help. (I reference in a separate class contained within my entire game class and use a global variable.) Here is the beginning code of my `onCreate()` method, Any suggestions?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    gamePrefs = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFS, 0);
    scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    timeText.setText(getString(R.string.timeText));
    start_count = new StartCount(3000,1000);
    background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    position0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.red);
    position1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yellow);
    position2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blue);
    position3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.green);
```

Relavant XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/score">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/space" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:radius="50dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/space"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blue" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:radius="50dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/yellow"
        android:radius="50dp"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:minWidth="225dp"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/score"
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/timeText"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/score" />
```

Comment: what is the variable you cant find?, and please show your XML

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify well, the compiler is unable to find (R.id.time). I have also included the relevant XML file

Comment: Is it the whole content of your .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your layout has more than one root element.

Try to modify your layout, for instance add the root `RelativeLayout` and place your layout inside it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/root"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <!--and here is your existing content-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/score"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        ...
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        ...
        android:typeface="monospace" />

</RelativeLayout>
```